# Using a designated initialiser VS a static method to populate a struct

Tags: swift, class, struct

I have been working on a struct that parses a JSON data, that data is from Dark sky. While I was working on it, something hit my brain and been pondering on it ever since.

Traditionally, we have been using designated initializers (although struct gives you a member-wise initializer for free) to instantiate an object. But, we could easily use a static function that returns itself and that function populates the properties.

like so:

```
struct WeatherForecastData {

    // Weather data

    var apparentTemperature: Double?
    var icon: String?
    var precipProbability: Double?
    var pressure: Double?


    static func map(_ data: [String: AnyObject]) -> WeatherForecastData {

        var p = WeatherForecastData()

        p.apparentTemperature = data["apparentTemperature"] as? Double ?? nil
        p.icon = data["icon"] as? String ?? nil
        p.precipProbability = data["precipProbability"] as? Double ?? nil
        p.pressure = data["pressure"] as? Double ?? nil

        return p
    }
}
```

notice the static method, if we replace it with a designated initializer, it would be doing the same thing as a static method. My question is when should we use static methods to instantiate an object instead of the traditional designated initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use a custom initializer like this?

```
struct WeatherForecastData {

    var apparentTemperature: Double

    var icon: String

    var precipProbability: Double

    var pressure: Double

    init?(data:Dictionary<String,Any>) {

        guard

            let apparentTemperature = data["apparentTemperature"] as? Double,

            let icon = data["icon"] as? String,

            let precipProbability = data["precipProbability"] as? Double,

            let pressure = data["pressure"] as? Double

        else {

            print("Invalid Data")

            return nil
        }

        self.apparentTemperature = apparentTemperature

        self.icon = icon

        self.precipProbability = precipProbability

        self.pressure = pressure
    }
}
```